# how to show that 5n=O(nlogn)

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I have this as a homework question and don't remember learning it in class. Can someone point me in the right direction or have documentation on how to solve these types of problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prove it by applying L'Hopitals rule to lim n-> infinity of 5n/nlogn

g(n) = 5n and f(n)=nlogn

Derivate g(n) and f(n) so you will get something like this

5/(some stuff here that will contain n)

5/infinity = 0 so 5n = O(nlogn) is true

Answer (score 2):

More formally...

First, we prove that if `f(n) = 5n`, then `f ∈ O(n)`. In order to show this, we must show that for some sufficiently large `k` and `i ≥ k`, `f(i) ≤ ci`. Fortunately, `c = 5` makes this trivial.

Next, I'll prove that for all `f ∈ O(n)` that `f ∈ O(n * log n)`. Hence, we must show that for some sufficiently large `k`, all `i ≥ k`, `f(i) ≤ ci * log i`. Hence, if we let `k` be large enough that `f(i) ≤ ci`, and `i ≥ 2`, then the result is trivial since `ci ≤ ci * log i`.

QED.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the definition of big-O-notation. It means that 5n will run no slower the nlogn, which is true. nlogn is an upper bound of the number of operations to be performed.

Comment: @Ellipsis: Assuming you were being sloppy with the notation, yes. If that's literally what you mean, no... you need to take the limit as n goes to infinity.

Comment: @Mehrdad yes, that's why I said to look at the definition, but you're right

Comment: could I cancel n out from both sides and say lim n->inf nlogn>5 ?

Comment: If that works better for you, then yes. But it should be obvious by looking at it that nlogn will grow faster than n as n goes to infinity

Comment: @Ellipsis: A more rigorous way to show that B(n) grows faster than A(n) is to show that `A(n)/B(n)` goes to zero as n goes to infinity. Try that here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember the wording of the formal definition, but what you have to show is:

c<sub>1</sub> * 5 * n <  c<sub>2</sub> * n * logn, n>c<sub>3</sub>

where c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub> are arbitrary constants, for some number c<sub>3</sub>.  Define c<sub>3</sub> in terms of c<sub>1</sub> and c<sub>2</sub>, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

It's been three years since I touched big-O stuff. But I think you can try to show this:

O(5n) = O(n) = O(nlogn)

O(5n) = O(n) is very easy to show, so all you have to do now is to show O(n) = O(nlogn) which shouldn't be too hard too.